# Fetching Directory Count

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need a little help with a little project I'm working on in C#.

Here is my code:

```
//TO FETCH DIRECTORY TEST
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Tahmid\Downloads"); 
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
```

Simply what I want it to do is see how many files is in my "Downloads" folder.

I ran into 2 problems though.

1. First problem is the word `System` is underlined in green and it says "Unreachable Code Detected".

   At first I thought It might be caused by a namespace I'm missing, I checked back at my code and saw I already have `using System.IO;` and `using System;`. I think these 2 are the one's I need for the directory count.

   So I am out of idea's on why its underlined green. xD
2. Second problem is that when I put those 2 lines of code into my project it breaks another section of my code which is this:

   ```
   case "switch window":
   SendKeys.Send("%{TAB " + count + "}");
   count += 1;
   break;
   ```

I get "count" underlined in blue saying "Use of unassigned local variable 'count'"

I'm quite baffled at the fact why the 2 lines of code to fetch the directory length break that.

Comment: [Update your question with the rest of your code as it is very unclear on what you have to determinate your problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17937393/edit) for instance to use `case` you need a `switch` and you're not showing us your `switch`, also we don't know if you are using the above code inside a function or event or where.

Comment: You have to show the whole code. All problems you described a based on the code outside of your examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to see more of your code to know the answers for sure... but here are some ideas that might help.

This would cause the first error

```
if (false)
{
   // this code is unreachable... false will never be true.
   //TO FETCH DIRECTORY TEST
   System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Tahmid\Downloads"); 
   int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
}
```

The second error is because you are using count before initializing it ... something like this:

```
int count;
/// ... more code
case "switch window":
  SendKeys.Send("%{TAB " + count + "}");  // uninitialized use.
  count += 1;
  break;
```

Where you need this:

```
int count;
count = 0;  // now count has a value.
/// ... more code
case "switch window":
  SendKeys.Send("%{TAB " + count.ToString() + "}");
  count += 1;
  break;
```

The 2nd being caused by the first is clear -- if the code is never reachable then it will never set count to a value so count is initialized.

Comment: Thanks, First error sorted I believe with your code. I still do have the second error now saying "A local variable named 'count' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'count', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else."

Comment: @user2632390 - you are declaring `count` twice, I suggest renaming one of them to something else, or if they are intended to be the same variable take the `int` out before one of them so you are not re-declaring it.

Comment: So how would I change it in the first snippet of code you gave me for the directory count? I'm still a newbie. :/

Comment: Take out the `int` -> `count = dir.GetFiles().Length;`

Comment: I tried removing the second part of the code so I only have the directory code but the the `if (false)` I get `if` underlined in green saying "unreachable code".

Comment: Here is the code: `if (false)
                    {
                        // this code is unreachable... false will never be true.
                        //TO FETCH DIRECTORY TEST
                        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Tahmid\Downloads");
                        int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
                    }`

Comment: yes, my code above was an example of something that would cause the problem

Comment: Then what would be the fix?

Comment: Not use false as the condition for the if, or remove the if part of the statement if you always want to perform the code.

Comment: Yay, Fixed. I have one last problem. After it gets the number of files in the directory: `int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;` I want the speech program to read out the number. How do I do that?

Comment: I was thinking something like: `JARVIS.Speak("You have" + dir.Length; + "files in your downloads folder");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh.. Start a new topic? :s